# Error in passing value from JS to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to pass a value from javascript to php using POST method but it is not working .Here is the code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Email()
{

    var e=prompt("Your Email","");
    if(e==null||e=="")
    {
    alert("You need to enter an email..Try again");
    Email();
    }

    return e;
}
function Code()
{

    var f=prompt("Activation code","");
    if(f==null||f=="")
    {
    alert("You need to enter the code..Try again");
    Code();
    }

    return f;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="Email" name="Email" />
<input type="hidden" id="Code" name="Code" />
</form> 
<script>
var email=Email();
var code=Code();
document.getElementByID("Email").value=email;
document.getElementByID("Code").value=code;
</script>

<?php
$email=$_POST["Email"];
$code=$_POST["Code"];

echo $email.$code;
?>
</body>
```

I get these errors :

- Notice: Undefined index: Email
- Notice: Undefined index: Code

Anybody please help me out...

Comment: It's `getElementById` (lowercase "d"), not `getElementByID`. Where is the code that does the post? You try to setup the `email` and `code` variables and put the values into the hidden fields, but you don't submit the form...

Comment: You are not passing anything by JavaScript. You are passing values by HTML form on this example. A form that does not even contain `submit` button.

Comment: how do you mean post to php? there is no action for the form and no js execution?

Comment: @nnnnnn : I have some work to do with them , but here I just echoed them .

Comment: @Qmal : I want to use these values in the same page .. I am a beginner , so can you tell what should my form tag look like ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey if you want to print those values you need to create a form form them, a proper one. If you just want to submit form no need for JS there because if you just want to submit some values there is no need for form, you want to use [jQuery Post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for that.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" />

    <label for="code">Code</label>
    <input type="text" name="code" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>​
```

Fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JWSN7/)

### Edit

Then [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JuaFR/) is what you want. (Note that this code is using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library)

```
$(function(){
    // Create both variables
    var code, email;

    // Ask for code and check if it's not null or empty
    do{
        code = prompt('Activation code', null);
    }
    while(code == null || code == '');


    // Ask for email and check if it's not null or empty
    do{
        email = prompt('Your email', null);
    }
    while(email == null || email == '');

    // Make POST request via AJAX to your script
    $.post('yourscript.php', { code: code, email: email }, function(data) {
        // If success alert response (in your case should be "email.data" values)
        alert(data);
    });   
});
```

Comment: Actually what I exactly want is that when a user comes to this page , he is validated .So a popup box will prompt and ask for his email and code.Then these data are matched from the database in a php script..Just to show it here I used echo it

Comment: @WayneRooney try new approach.

Comment: Ok..Thank you.. I did the entire thing in php and removed the js part..I just added another field in the landing page which validates the users